# Validating if single char is char

Tags: c++, iostream, formatted-input

I want to validate if a char is actually a char. When user inputs a string of letters "abc" program will say that user must enter a single char.

I was thinking about using

```
if(sizeof(userLetter != 1))
{
    cout << "Enter only a single letter."
}
```

The problem is since userLetter is initialized as a character it automatically truncates remainder of letters and thinks user only input one letter.

Is there a way to check if user really only input 1 letter without initializing userLetter as a string?

Comment: C++ is statically typed. A char is a char.

Comment: Read the whole line, not just a character.

Comment: How are you doing the input?  Is it using cin or getline or something else?

Comment: cin.get(userLetter)

Comment: You will need to read a whole line of input, and check whether or not it has more than 1 character

Comment: Regardless this code is not doing what you want it to do. You'd want to do `sizeof(userLetter) == sizeOf(char)`. The condition will give you the size of an `int` as `userLetter != 1` resolves to an `int`.

Comment: @EliSadoff Wouldn't it resolve to basically `sizeof(bool)`?

Comment: Your `if` statement, as written, is equivalent to `if (sizeof(bool))`, which is always true because C++ doesn't support zero-size types.

Comment: @DeiDei It depends upon the version of C++. If `bool` exists in that version, then yes, otherwise it will be `int`.

Comment: @EliSadoff: You'd need a *really* old C++ compiler in order to lack support for `bool`.  Even so, the `sizeof` a Boolean expression (whether it's of type `bool` or `int`) is always positive, so the condition is always true.  I assume the OP meant `if (sizeof(userLetter) != 1)`, which is still incorrect: `sizeof` is not `strlen`.

Comment: @dan04 That's true.  `sizeof(userletter) == sizeof(char)` will be the right way to do it, but that will always be true if `userletter` is of type `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your reading a char, it will only read one and keep the following chars in the buffer.

If you want to take all what the user types until he presses the first enter, you need to get a line:

```
 string line; 
 while (getline(cin, line) && (line.length()==0 || line.length()>1) )  
    cout << "Enter only a single letter..."<<endl;
```

When this ends successfuly, get the first char of string with `userLetter = line[0];`